# Selecting an item from select box ,how to display contents from database?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, oracle10g

My jsp page

```
<select name="se">
  <option value="1">D1</option>
  <option value="2">D2</option>
  <option value="3">D3</option>
</select>
```

While the user selects D1,then in the same page i want to display the contents from the database.

I want the same for D2,D3.

Where should i write the select query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onchange` event to make an call to server. On server side you can handle the request and return the required result from database and show it or alternatively you can pre-fetch result from database while calling jsp and just can show/hide `onchange` event.

like using jQuery

```
<select onchange="$('divId').show()"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` event to get the select box value and through ajax, pass value to the servlet.

Go through with this:

http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/comboSelect.shtml